# In Google Sheets, how to "combine" 2 cols, but make the result be the 1st col repeated with 2nd col data

Tags: google-sheets

In Col A, I have a list of names.
e.g.

```
  Bob Jones
  John Doe
  Sally Smithers
```

In Col B, I have a list of dates.
e.g.

```
  6/1/23
  6/2/23
  6/3/23
```

Both lists are dynamic and can have different #'s of rows.

I want to "combine" the cols but have the result be *2* columns with each name repeated and the dates repeated, like this:

| Name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Bob Jones | 6/1/23 |
| Bob Jones | 6/2/23 |
| Bob Jones | 6/3/23 |
| John Doe | 6/1/23 |
| John Doe | 6/2/23 |
| John Doe | 6/3/23 |
| Sally Smithers | 6/1/23 |
| Sally Smithers | 6/2/23 |
| Sally Smithers | 6/3/23 |

I *do* already have a formula for this that's been working:
`transpose(ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(A2:A&"@@",count(B:B))), "@@"))))`

But my lists are getting longer and I'm running into the "Text result of CONCATENATE is longer than the limit of 50000 characters" limit.

Is there a better way to do this that let's me do this with longer lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with REDUCE:

```
=REDUCE({"Name","Date"},TOCOL(A:A,1),LAMBDA(a,name,{a;BYROW(TOCOL(B:B,1),LAMBDA(date,{name,date}))}))
```

[image]

REDUCE does not concatenate the cells but iterates over a range and performs a cumulative action. Working with those curly brackets and BYROW you're able to just stack the cells, without joining and splitting